# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity with custom tables configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to build an authentication functionality using Identity Core 2.0 with my own custom tables and EF Core 2.0.

I am using this for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1.

The thing is I'm not using Roles, nor Claims so I have a single Table/`DbSet` containing the user information. I've implemented the required interfaces and everything looks fine. I am also using JWT authentication. The problem is I am not sure how to configure the services in the Startup. Here is my current code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"]))
            };
        });

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));           

    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
        //.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

where `User` is my custom implementation of the user class. Same goes for `UserStore`.

However, I am not sure how to configure the specific Identity services. I am supposed to call `services.AddIdentity`, but it requires a parameter of type `TRole` which I am not implementing and there isn't any variation without providing a role type. I either have to implement dummy/use the `IdentityRole` or I have to extract the contents of the extension method and add them manually, which doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Furthermore, it adds Cookie Auth by default, so it won't cut it for me. Here is the body of the extension method I've found: [ASP.NET Identity Ref-1](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/efe0c6be7b1847b2fa3f774ef85de5c8aa4493d4/src/Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) / [ASP.NET Identity Ref-2](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

How should I register the services? Also, am I missing something else in the configuration in general given the circumstances(JWT, Identity with custom tables).

Comment: I learned that it’s easiest to just live with all the things Identity already gives you, and just ignore the stuff you don’t need. So yeah, you will end up with a few database tables and lots of stuff, but you don’t need to *use* any of that.

Comment: if you want to go completely manual, you can have a look at this approach https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore-jwt-sample/blob/master/website/Services/TokenAuthScheme.cs